# IntelliJ IDEA: make HTTP/2 requests with HTTP client

Tags: intellij-idea, httprequest, http2, web-development-server

There is [HTTP client](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/http-client-in-product-code-editor.html) in IDEA. It allows to save HTTP requests to web servers in a files and run its later. It helps in development very well.

Simple GET request:

```
### GET request with a header
GET https://httpbin.org/ip
Accept: application/json
```

But request can be made to HTTP/1 & HTTPS servers only.

Is it possible to make request to HTTP/2 servers with IDEA HTTP client?

Answer (score 3):

HTTP/2 is not yet supported in IntelliJ IDEA. Here is the feature request for that: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-188869

Please vote and follow for updates.